# Facebook Graph API: Get Link attached to post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When using Facebook in the browser, it is possible to attach a link to a post without the link being in the message text: Simply type the link, wait for the link preview window to show, delete your text again.

[image: This is how it looks like]

How can I get the link (StackOverflow.com) using Graph API? I can retrieve the post object from a public page, but the link is not shown. I only get the text of the post, but not the attached link.

Comment: _I only get "Link removed (but still attached)"_ - where, by what/whom? Doesn’t sound like an official API response ... Do you have an example of such a post?

Comment: "Link removed" is simply the text that I have written in the post myself. I have clarified my question.

Comment: Are you looking at the `message` field only? The shared link is in the `link` field.

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. The link field has the required information.